# Open a link in web browser using flash swf

Tags: actionscript, flash-cs5

I am new to flash coding and didn't know much more.

I want to make a flash file that send URL to web browser to open particular link.

I've made such file it execute properly but after making swf file, it does not open the link.

Any one help me regarding this small problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out `navigateToURL()`: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/package.html#navigateToURL()

Note that it won't work unless it's triggered by a user action; i.e. a mouse click or a key press

Comment: Assuming AS3, this should work fine: `var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest( "http://www.google.com" );
navigateToURL( request, "_blank" );`
This will open Google in a new window - check out the `navigateToURL()` docs for the other params that you can add. If this doesn't work, can you post the error message that you're getting?